# Count rows in a dataframe column if not some specific values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hi is have a multi column dataframe and want to print the sum of column rows if those are not `nan` or `-` or `?`

```
Col1   Col2   Col3    
this   nan     1
that    ?      2
those  this    5
these  that    2
there   -      1
```

i want the result to be

```
print df['Col2].count()  # Im missing the not ( nan or ? or - ) part here
2
```

Comment: `df['Col2'].replace('^[?-]|nan$', np.nan, regex=True).notna().sum()` ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chain mask created by [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) with inverted checking membership by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
mask = df['Col2'].notna() & ~df['Col2'].isin(['?','-', 'nan'])
#if no missing values only strings nan
#mask = ~df['Col2'].isin(['?','-', 'nan'])
print (mask.sum())
2
```

**Detail**:

```
print (mask)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
Name: Col2, dtype: bool
```

Comment: I think here you are counting only what is in the `(['?','-', 'nan'])` list i want to exclude this list.

Comment: @Codeburn - then only omit `df['Col2'].notna() & `, but if sometimes `NaN` is missing value is necessary also `df['Col2'].notna() & `

Answer (score 0):

Jezrael was close enough, but as i wanted to exclude what was in the list the proper code is this :

```
mask = df['Col2'].notna() & ~df['Col2'].isin(['?','-', 'nan'])
print (mask.sum())
2
```

just putting a `~` before the filter acting as `not`